# up /down navigation for table created using flex in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, flexbox

I have created a table using flex as follows.

```
<form #consolidatedForm="ngForm">
                            <div class="flex-row" *ngFor="let item of model.balance.Assets; let i = index;">
                                <div class="flex-cell w-2 border border-no-bottom border-no-top border-no-left"> {{item.description | stringShorten:48}} </div>
                                <div class="flex-cell border border-no-left calculated" *ngFor="let value of item.wacValues"> {{value.value | wacNumber}} </div>
                                <div class="flex-cell border border-no-left" style="padding:1px 2px 1px 1px;">
                                    <input type="number" [disabled]="syncing" style="border:none;" [(ngModel)]="item.eliminationAdjustment"
                                           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" name="eliminationadjustment + i" (change)="syncCurrentAssets()" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex-cell border border-no-left calculated"> {{item.consolidatedStatement | wacNumber:true}} </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Is there any possible way to navigate between each cells in flex row in angular 6?.I could find the solution only for tables that are not created using the flex.

Comment: I highly recommend using fxFlex - https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlex-API

Comment: Are you using AngularJS ort Angular 6? Or, perhaps, both (and that would be quite interesting!!!)?

Comment: am using angular 6

Comment: i can't change the flex class since it is up to client